# Python Selenium can't find element in iframe window

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium was able to find another element within the iframe. See code below:

```
# Switch to iframe window    
browser.switch_to.frame("edit-page-body_ifr")
# Select the text
text_box = browser.find_element_by_id('tinymce')
text_box.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, 'a')
```

But can't find this element:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('edit-page-body_fontsizeselect_text').click()
```

HTML code for this element:

```
<a id="edit-page-body_fontsizeselect_text" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:;" class="mceText mceTitle" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">12</a>
```

Error code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"edit-page-body_fontsizeselect_text"}
```

[image: Element I'm trying to find.]

Comment: Is it appeared just after text selected or it present all the time?

Comment: Appears the same time as the text... I think. I'll try an explicit wait to see if this works.

Comment: It appears at the same time, `time.sleep(2)` didn't help.

Comment: Maybe it is located in another `iframe`?

Comment: How would I find out?

Comment: I ran `ele = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')` and then `for e in ele: print e.text` the output was just the text. So I exited out of the iframe and it picked up the element. Thank for the help and tip @Andersson. Greatly appreciated.